# JWT authentication for jBASE RESTful API

Tags: rest, jwt, jbase

We are in the process of designing a front-end application with Angular which will call a jBASE server through RESTful APIs. APIs are created from jBASE component called jAgent.

1. Does jAgent support creating and verifying JWTs?
2. If not, what is the best way to handle authentication/authorization for the Angular application?
3. If we need to use JWTs, do we have to use a authentication middleware application (.NET Core or node.js) for that?

Comment: jAgent for jBASE - https://jbase.helpjuice.com/30312-jagent/introduction-to-jagent-rest-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question! At the moment there is no handler within jAgent and our recommendation is to implement this, and advanced web server/API gateway technology by way of other applications like [HAproxy](https://www.haproxy.org/) or [Kong](https://konghq.com/).

An expansion of jAgent functionality to include things like this *is* something we're still considering but keep in mind, the power of jBASE lies in its native interactions with the host OS. Since there is no virtual OS layer it can be easier to plug and play off the shelf things to fill in for additional functionality, which gives you the flexibility to bring your own tooling.

In summary:

1. Not at the moment
2. Using an off the shelf package to act as your API gateway
3. Subject to the package you choose

That relegates jAgent to management of the API layer as it exists on the PICK/jBASE side while the off the shelf package manages your API security layer.

One other note for you--I noticed that you included a link to the old jBASE docs hosted on HelpJuice. It's worth mentioning that we've migrated those docs to [docs.zumasys.com](https://docs.zumasys.com). You'll find the docs there to be more up to date, and also completely open sourced--part of the migration included their move to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/zumasys/docs), where we're happy to take community contributions.

For reference, the article you mentioned is available at https://docs.zumasys.com/jbase/connectivity/jagent/introduction-to-jagent-rest-services/.

Update:

One of our engineers has a program that will use openssl to generate the tokens for you, which you can find at https://github.com/patrickp/wjwt.

> You will need [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) installed on the machine and in the path.
>
> The `WJWT.TEST` program shows the usage. The important piece is the `SECRET.KEY` which is your internal `KEY` you use to sign the payloads.
>
> When a user first authenticates you create the token with `SIGN`. Claims are any items/fields you wish to save/store. Do *NOT* put sensitive data in here as it is viewable by anybody. The concept is we sign this with our key, give it back to the client. On future calls the client sends the token and we pull it and call the `VERIFY` function which basically re-signs the payload and validates the signatures match. This validates the payload was not manipulated.
>
> Activities such as expiration you would build into your code.
>
> Long term we plan to take this library and refactor the code into our `MVDB Toolkit` library with more functionality. That library is something we provide to jBASE customers at no additional charge.

Comment: Thanks for this information Mike. I will check up on Kong as an option.

Comment: Certainly. If you do want to pursue a PICK based path here I can offer an alternative, though again, this is not memorialized into the product at this time. I've amended the answer above to include this info.